# HQL query is not working as expected

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, ejb-3.0, jpql

My server side component is EJB along with JPA.

**My Entity looks as follow**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4235645698986231545L;

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeId id;

@Column
private String designation;

public Employee() {
}

public EmployeeId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(EmployeeId id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getDesignation() {
    return this.designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

}
```

**Embedded Entity**

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4542369821217566566L;

@Column(name = "emp_id")
private Integer empId;

@Size(max = 10)
private String name;


public EmployeeId() {
}


public Byte getEmpId() {
    return this.empId;
}

public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.stationId;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

My Table looks like this

**employee**

**========**

```
emp_id | name | designation |
==============|==============
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | yyyy | programmer  |
1002   | zzzz | tester      |
1003   | aaaa | HR          |
1004   | bbbb | Admin       |
1005   | cccc | Manager     |
1006   | dddd | programmer  |
1007   | eeee | programmer  |
1008   | ffff | programmer  |
1008   | gggg | programmer  |
=============================
```

My JPQL query is

```
String query = "from Employee where designation = :design ";

public List<Employee> find(String designation) {

     return getEntityManager().createQuery(query).setParameter("design", designation).getResultList();
 }
```

My expected result is the following. I get this while querying manually

```
emp_id | name | designation |
==============|==============
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | yyyy | programmer  |
1006   | dddd | programmer  |    6 rows
1007   | eeee | programmer  |
1008   | ffff | programmer  |
1008   | gggg | programmer  |
=============================
```

But what i'm getting is through JPQL output

```
emp_id | name | designation |
==============|==============
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |    6 rows
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
1001   | xxxx | programmer  |
=============================
```

Why is it giving duplicate values but correct number of rows? What is the problem how can I fix this?

Comment: Not saw any issue here. Make sure you are not printing the first result over and over inside the loop.

Comment: That's HQL not JPQL; there's a difference. And if using HQL then tag your question as Hibernate, since it is not JPQL.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen JPQL select statements written *without* the `select` keyword before; I can't say conclusively that it's wrong, but you might try reformulating your query as follows:

```
String query = "select e from Employee e where e.designation = :design ";
```

I'd also suggest replacing the table name "employee" with the class name "Employee" (as shown above).  Again, I don't know that what you are doing is wrong, but I've always used the (unqualified) Java class names rather than the table names in my JPQL.

Here are some more examples: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Select_query_examples